# Static object lifetime in a shared library with a destructor method

Tags: c++, gcc, shared-libraries

I have a cross-platform dynamic library that uses an internal static logger object. I want to be able to log the loading/unloading of the library - In Windows this works quite nice since I'm able to log both events when `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` and `DLL_PROCESS_DETTACH` invocations of `DllMain` happen. On Linux, my approach was to have `__attribute__((constructor))` and `__attribute__((destructor))` methods that would do the same, something along these lines:

```
CLog Log;

static void __attribute__((constructor))
VirtualBoxCaptureSourceLoaded(void)
{
    Log.Initialize("/var/log/my-test-log.log");
    LOG("=== Start ===");
}

static void __attribute__((destructor))
VirtualBoxCaptureSourceUnloaded(void)
{
    LOG("=== Stop ===");
}
```

However, this failed since the `Log` object is destroyed when the destructor is invoked? The question is - can I control this anyhow (compiler flags, attributes for the destructor, ...) or is my only option to use a pointer instead of an object and destroy it manually in the destructor?

Comment: Why don't you log from your CLog's contructor and destructor?

Comment: @Mat, mainly because of the Windows workflow - in debug build I log when a thread attaches and detaches from the dll and so on, but since I guess I'm not able to catch that in Linux logging in the ctor/dtor can be an alternative to having a pointer. I wanted to have the log class free of actual logging to separate the implementation from the actual logging.

Comment: This is the static initialization order fiasco in reverse.  You are possibly ahead with `extern CLog Log;` and put `CLog Log` after these functions.  But with the risk that now the constructor fails :(

Comment: @HansPassant well I kind of leaned towards that, and yeah that is exactly what I'm doing - using an `extern` declaration of the class and using an instance per each shared library. Oh well, I hoped there could be some means to control the behavior of the gcc ctor/dtor but I guess I'm facing a classical issue:) Thanks for the comment.